# twilio dynamic voice url number?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using twlio REST API in my PHP application to make phone calls.

everything works fine as it should.

however, I would need to allow the users to use their own phone number if they want.

For this I don't know how I should proceed because my current twilio voice URL is an static URL (PHP file with XML output) which has the caller ID within it!

I can simply verify the numbers via rest api and add them to my twilio account but how would I then use those numbers in my application dynamically as opposed to adding them manually to the voice URL page?

this is my voice URL page:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// put a phone number you've verified with Twilio to use as a caller ID number
$callerId = "+44XXXXXXXX0";

// put your default Twilio Client name here, for when a phone number isn't given
$number   = "Michelle";

// get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
if (isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'])) {
    $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']);
}

// wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
// by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
    $numberOrClient = "<Number>" . $number . "</Number>";
} else {
    $numberOrClient = "<Client>" . $number . "</Client>";
}
?>

<Response>
    <Dial callerId="<?php echo $callerId ?>">
          <?php echo $numberOrClient ?>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

REVISED

To allow the user to choose their own Caller ID while making calls, we'll assume you've already provided a way in your web UI for them to specify their phone number so that you can verify it with the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest).

Once verified, you could save their phone number to their user profile, represented below by `$UserVerifiedCallerID`, so that you can easily pass that number to your Client script.

```
var params = {
    "PhoneNumber": $("#number").val(),
    "VerifiedCallerID": "<?php echo $UserVerifiedCallerID; ?>"
};
Twilio.Device.connect(params);
```

When Twilio calls back to your [PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) script to get the TwiML for handling that call, Twilio will send the `VerifiedCallerID` parameter, which you can use to set `$callerId`:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// Grab the VerfiedCallerID from the request
$callerId = $_REQUEST['VerifiedCallerID'];

...
```

Now when your user makes calls, their own Verified Caller ID will show instead of a hard-coded number.

Comment: I'm sorry but your instructions confused the hell out of me! Also, I am already doing most if not all of the stuff in my application and that is why I stated that **everything works fine as it should.**  This is exactly what I do and as I said it works fine and makes calls etc etc: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls   The issue that I described was not about making calls, it is in fact for allowing users to choose their own number whilst making calls. in the example above, the Voice URL and the page that make a call from are different!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @H.HISTORY. I've narrowed my answer to focus on the variables needed to make Caller ID dynamic in both your Client script and your PHP script. Let me know if you need additional details.